# react router v6: How to get history stack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a router like this

```
<MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/a', '/b']} initialIndex={0}>
...
</MemoryRouter>
```

When it renders `/a`, how can I check the history stack (i.e. `['/a', '/b']`) so I know if I can go forward or not?

Comment: RRDv6 routers maintain their own history contexts, generally. If you want to know if you can navigate forward/backward you'll need to keep and maintain your own history stack. What is the use case here, duplicate the browser navigation buttons?

Comment: *sad song on world's smallest violin*

Comment: Agreed, with the current approach you have to keep track of it yourself. I will note that there is *theoretically* hope for the future with the new navigation api: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/navigation-api/